Нужен совет по переходу на другой язык программирования
Являюсь PHP разработчиком, джун. Хочу перейти на другой язык, пока думаю на Go.
Нужен ваш совет, стоит ли переходить на другой язык и если ответ да, то на какой.
Будет ли тяжело найти работу на языке Go джуну.
Если не тяжело, прошу дать развернутый ответ, так как сам не опытен

Открываешь сайты вакансий и смотришь востребованность. Это всё что можно сказать по твоему "вопросу", который не по теме ресурса.
